# Why does this old user have an unclickable profile, yet retain the profile name by their posts?

Tags: support, users, user-accounts

This user

[image]

looks like a deleted user, but unlike most (all?) users, they retain their username - usually a deleted user become *user123456* or something random number.

Is this a bug? What happened to the user?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note the date. There was a time way back that user names were not anonymized on deletion. That looks to have been added sometime post this user being deleted.

Relevant stack meta [Why is this non-anonymous username on this non-migrated question greyed out and not a link?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295805/why-is-this-non-anonymous-username-on-this-non-migrated-question-greyed-out-and/295806#295806)